# Redirect command requests to another service

Tags: slack-api

I have a not yet published app change in Slack which modifies the command service endpoint to another domain.
I tested that, **it is possible to send back a 307 with a redirect URL and Slack API will follow that redirect.**

I would like to be sure that redirect to another domain is **also possible for live apps**. So what works for an in-development app it will work for a live app.

**Could any of you confirm that or send me a link to the documentation? I searched the documentation already, but did not find any entry about it.**

Thanks!

Comment: This is an important questions and unfortunately I do not know the answer. Would suggest to contact the Slack team directly to clarify. (and would be great if you could share the result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We contacted Slack on their partner channel and they verified that:

"Our docs explicitly say we respect 301 and 302."

**But we made a test and it accepts 307 as well.**

(I can't share a link to their response as it was written inside Slack slack-platform workspace)